# Can locked items only be opened with a lock pick?

Tags: resident-evil-7

A locked chest:

[image]

"Small keyhole" legend on the map, excludes locked doors. Lock picks are disposable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those types of locks can only be opened with a lock pick.

Usually you can find a lockpick not far after finding a locked container.

After my first playthrough I had 2 spare lockpicks at the end o the game. However, I expect I overlooked at least 1 locked box, maybe more, so I can't say with any certainty if there is the exact number of lockpicks to locks.

---

Side note: later in the game there are different locks that require a different tool. Whether or not you can use the lockpick on these I don't know, however you certainly can't use the new tool on the containers you have mentioned as there is no way back to those areas at that point in the game.

Comment: There is exactly same count of locks and lock-picks in game. If you have any spare lock-picks, this means, you missed some locked container, and your lock-pick will have no use after point of no return.

Comment: Also, lock-picks placement is completely independent of locks locations.